# Background service in azure planned to run at scheduled time

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I need to create a background job. There is NO trigger point for this. 
It should run at FIXED time every day. It need to fetch data from some external API and update our application database. I need to setup it in Azure. What managed service I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Functions or Azure Webjobs. Both support schedule:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#CreateScheduledCRON
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer

Azure Automation might be the answer also, depending on your language preference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-schedules

Comment: yeah, I've mentioned that in my answer ;)